# Event Listeners in Backbone View are not being added to objects in the DOM

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js, backbone-events

I've been struggling through my first Backbone app and have started to get the hang of things. I now have a few successful reports that load JSON data from my server (NodeJS), populate a template (Handlebars), and render relatively nicely on the frontend.

The issue I'm running into is that I'm trying to add event handlers to a `<select>` object coming in from one of my templates and I'm not having much luck.

Here's the **template**:

```
// Report - New Clients

script(type='text/x-handlebars-template', id='newClients-template')
  // Start Listing
  {{#each report}}
  .listingName
    .youSearched
      | Stylist:
    .srchResult
      select.chzn-select(id='stylists', style='width:350px')
        option(value='null') All Stylists
        {{#each stylists}}
        option(value='{{uid}}') {{name}}
        {{/each}}
  .clear
```

And here's the **Backbone View:**
*note: I'm calling the view from within a `$ ->` so it shouldn't be loading until `DocumentReady`*

```
  # View
  class window.NewClientsView extends Backbone.View

    events: 
      'click #stylists': 'selectStylist'
  
    initialize: ->
      @el = $('.containerOuter')
      _.bindAll this, 'render'
      @collection.bind 'reset', @render

      # Compile Handlebars template at init (Not sure if we have to do this each time or not)
      source = $('#newClients-template').html()
      @template = Handlebars.compile source

      # Get the latest collections
      @collection.fetch()

    render: ->
      # Render Handlebars template
      renderedContent = @template { report: @collection.toJSON() }
      $(@el).html renderedContent

      return this

    selectStylist: (e) ->
      console.log 'hit it!'
      console.log e
```

I'm expecting that any time the dropdown is clicked or changed, I'll see the `selectStylist` function fired. Unfortunately that hasn't happened yet :( I also have inspected the element in Chrome Dev Tools and there are no event listeners set on the object.

I've been stuck on this for a bunch of hours now and have reviewed all the other suggestions for Backbone event listeners (i.e. pass in your `this.el` as a parameter when instantiating your view), but haven't had any success.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `initialize`, you write

```
@el = $('.containerOuter')
```

But Backbone.js processes `events` *before* `initialize`—meaning that it's already bound those events to a different `@el` (which you should see in the DOM as a lonely `div`).

You can hack this by overriding `make`, the function that's used to create `@el`:

```
make: ->
  $('.containerOuter')[0]
```

Comment: Relax; everything is behaving as it should. Backbone uses jQuery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), for two reasons: First, a `bind` has to be done every time the target element is created. Second, `delegate` is more efficient. A single `click` delegate on `containerOuter` can listen for `click` events on thousands of child elements, without cluttering the DOM with extra listeners.

Comment: (That comment was written in response to one that was subsequently deleted, asking why the events seemed—from Chrome's Dev Tools—to be bound to the `.containerOuter` element.)